# Want to play button animation to the end as it has been fired

Tags: silverlight, events, animation

I have a button.  I set an awesome animation to my button. It fires when the button has been clicked.  But, if finger release button TOO quickly - animation will fade to initial values, so user will NOT see all the beauty of my animation.  Also I have an event for this button...

What I want: User press button >> Animation starts and plays to the end >> logic-event trigger fires.

The question is - can I do it SIMPLE way? Setting some values in XAML?

Because the only way I know is:

User press button >> In code fires event trigger, that fires my animation >> animation-completed-trigger fires my logic-event.

Is there a way to achieve it more simply?

Thanks.